# How to get custom error body message in WebClient properly?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

What i trying to achieve is to get my response error with 404 code and the error body with WebClient, how do i do this properly?

here is my response with error code 404 and the body response from another API :

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-09-02T07:36:01.960+00:00",
  "message": "Data not found!",
  "details": "uri=/api/partnershipment/view"
}
```

and here is how my consuming code looked like :

```
    Map<String,Long> req = new HashMap<String,Long>();
    req.put("id", 2L);

    PartnerShipmentDto test = webClient.post()
    .uri(urlTest).body(Mono.just(req), PartnerShipmentDto.class)
    .exchange()
    .flatMap(res -> {
        if(res.statusCode().isError()){
            res.body((clientHttpResponse, context) -> {
                throw new ResourceNotFound(clientHttpResponse.getBody().toString());
            });
            throw new ResourceNotFound("aaaa");

        } else {
            return res.bodyToMono(PartnerShipmentDto.class);
        }
    })
    .block();
```

and here is my ResourNotFound.java class :

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFound extends RuntimeException {
    
    public ResourceNotFound(String message){
        super(message);
    }
    
}
```

and here is my Global Exception handler using @ControllerAdvice :

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {

        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFound.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFound ex, WebRequest request) {

        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

but the response i got printed in my ResourceNotFound exception is like this (this is my error from consumer side) :

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-09-02T07:50:48.132+00:00",
  "message": "FluxMap",
  "details": "uri=/api/shipmentaddressgrouping/store"
}
```

it written "FluxMap" only, how i get the "message" field? i would like to get the "timestamp" and "details" field too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with the example code you have give is the following line of code

```
throw new ResourceNotFound(clientHttpResponse.getBody().toString());
```

The type of this is `Flux<DataBuffer>`, not the actual response body. This is leading to the issue you are seeing.

The way to solve this is invoking the `bodyToMono` method on the error response body and mapping to a java object. This can be done via the `onStatus` operator expose from the web client that allows you to take specific actions on specific status codes.

The code snippet below should resolve this

```
    webClient.post()
            .uri(uriTest).body(Mono.just(req), PartnerShipmentDto.class)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, res -> res.bodyToMono(ErrorBody.class)
                    .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.error(new ResourceNotFound("aaaa")))
                    .flatMap(errorBody -> Mono.error(new ResourceNotFound(errorBody.getMessage())))
            )
            .bodyToMono(PartnerShipmentDto.class)
            .block();
```

The class `ErrorBody` should contain all of the fields you want to map from json to the java object. The example below only maps the "message" field.

```
public class ErrorBody {
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: woah it solved my error message, just to clear my mind, i read somewhere which is said, if we use retreive(), we can't get the error status, it led my to change my code from retrieve() to exchange(), but u make retreive() worked, when should i use retrieve() or exchange()?

Comment: I would advise to use retrieve() as much as possible as this is what is recommended in the javadocs. Read the note in the docs below for an explanation
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.html#exchange--

Comment: thank u very much for the explanation Michael, that made my day :)